# Found in common SSD advice, but how does 2,048 equates to 1MB?

Tags: linux, ssd, filesystems

I'm trying to set up a Linux partition on my laptop and I've run into the same phrase all over the internet. It's on one of the superuser answers...

In the question [Which linux filesystem works best with SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/228657/which-linux-filesystem-works-best-with-ssd), the top answer says:

> In Linux, simply run fdisk -cu (device) on the drive you want to
>   partition, press n for new partition, p for primary and enter a start
>   sector of at least 2,048. The general rule is that the starting sector
>   must be divisible by 512, but to cater for all variations of SSD page
>   size and filesystem block size, **2,048 is a good idea (and equates to
>   1MB**).

How does 2,048 equate to 1MB (1024?)

Comment: The quote you provided explains how its equal to 1MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sector size is 512 bytes. 2048 sectors x 512 bytes = 1 Mbyte

Answer (score 2):

2048 blocks, each 512 bytes (half a kilobyte) is 1024 KB is 1MB.