# Linux won't boot with f2fs

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, filesystems

I recently had a hardware failure and replaced by old HDD with an SSD. Therefore I used f2fs for my root partition. But now I am unable to boot properly due to fsck failure. I keep getting the following output during boot:

```
=> Welcome to Void!
=> Mounting pseudo-filesystems...
=> Loading kernel modules...
=> Starting udev and waiting for devices to settle...
=> Setting up keymap to 'de-latin1-nodeadkeys'...
=> Remounting rootfs read-only...
=> Activating btrfs devices...
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
=> Activating encrypted filesystems...
=> Checking filesystems:
Info: Fix the reported corruption.
Info: Mounted device!
Info: Check FS only on RO mounted device
        Error: Failed to open the device!
Cannot continue due to errors above, starting emergency shell.
```

As only the filesystem check fails, I am still able to boot by simply exiting the emergency shell.

According to the log, the filesystem should theoretically be mounted read-only. I don't understand what's the actual issue here and how I can solve it.

I am running Void Linux with a 6.6.16 kernel.

*Update: The filesystem seems to be read-only when still in the emergency shell.*

```
$ mount -l -t f2fs
/dev/sda2 on / type f2fs (ro,relatime,lazytime,backgrou...
```

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/F2FS

Comment: Honestly, f2fs isn't worth it unless you are dealing with a 10+ year old solid state drive... modern drives have gotten go so good that doing anything special for them in way of filesystem or such is not necessary.

Comment: So, what do you recommend? Simply use EXT4 like suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/228657/which-linux-filesystem-works-best-with-ssd)?

Comment: Yes, ext4 is fine... or brtfs or whatever you wish. I have been using btrfs for years on ssd and never had any issues. The point is you don't have to do anything special for modern SSD's, just use them like normal, the question you are referencing is 13 years old and doesn't really apply anymore in modern hardware. Most SSD drives will outlive physical HDDs.